# Когда нужно использовать ResolveUrl, а когда ResolveClientUrl

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Я знаю, что ResolveClientUrl возвращает путь относительно текущей страницы, а ResolveUrl - относительно корня сайта.
Хотелось бы узнать, в каких случаях один метод будет выгоднее использовать, чем другой.

Comment: в чем вы хотите измерять выгоду?

Comment: Мне зочется узнать, какой метод правильнее использовать, и почему.
Может в каких-то ситуациях результат одного из этих методов не будет соответствовать ожиданиям.
В общем, хочу понять зачем нужно было создавать два разных метода со схожей функциональностью.

Comment: из мсдн для ResolveClientUrl: [_URL-адрес, возвращенный этим методом, определяется относительно папки, содержащей файл источника в котором создан элемент управления.Элементы управления, которые наследуют это свойство, например UserControl и MasterPage, возвращают полный URL-адрес относительно элемента управления._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Пусть имеется картинка: ~/Images/1.jpg;
Имеется юзер контрол: ~/dir/dir/myControl.ascx;
Этот юзер контрол используется в Default.aspx;

В контроле я укажу две картинки: <img src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Images/1.jpg")%>'/> и <img src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/1.jpg")%>'/>.

В итоге на клиенте будут показаны две одинаковые картинки, т.к для них сгенерируются следующие url'ы: <img src="/Images/1.jpg">
и <img src="Images/1.jpg">

Т.е. ResolveClientUrl вернет путь относительно страницы Default.aspx.
Про что тогда говорится на msdn'е?

Comment: ох, лучше бы это было в вопрос добавить и отформатировать :-) присмотритесь внимательно и увидите разницу: `<img src="/Images/1.jpg">` есть слеш в начала адреса, следовательно браузер будет искать картинку в корне сайта, `<img src="Images/1.jpg">` нет слеша в начале адреса, а значит картинки будут искаться на уровне текущей страницы. Все зависит от того по какому адресу вы открываете страницу

Comment: Это я понял.
Мне хочется узнать ситуации, где правильнее использовать путь относительно корня (<img src="/Images/1.jpg">), а где относительно страницы (<img src="Images/1.jpg">).
Зачем нужно было создавать две таких варианта доступа к ресурсу. Почему нельзя было сделать доступ к ресурсу по пути относительно корня. Не для красоты же сделали два варианта.

Comment: вообще, это должно было работать так: если юзер контрол, например папка, в которой сам контролл и все его стили, картинки и т.д. Этот контрол может быть на любой странице, и путь который резолвится внутри на стили картинки и т.д. - должны резолвится относительно папки контрола

Comment: Но работает так: с помощью метода ResolveClientUrl путь будет относительно страницы, в которой лежит юзер контрол. Поэтому не понятно, что в MSDN имеется в виду.

Comment: вот два таких же вопроса [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518199/control-resolveurl-versus-control-resolveclienturl-versus-virtualpathutility-toa) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874636/what-is-the-difference-between-resolveurl-and-resolveclienturl) - пришли к выводу - что разницы нет, но чаще используют  ResolveUrl

Comment: Я уже читал эти вопросы, но только сейчас заметил, что там говорится про кодирование. И правда метод ResolveClientUrl кодирует путь, в отличие от ResolveUrl.
Спасибо.